# prove that a conjugate of a glide reflection is a glide reflection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

This question has an answer elsewhere, [a conjugate of a glide reflection by any isometry of the plane is again a glide reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508875/a-conjugate-of-a-glide-reflection-by-any-isometry-of-the-plane-is-again-a-glide), but they use results which were not mentioned in the book. The question comes from Artin's Algebra 6.3:

"Prove that a conjugate of a glide reflection is a glide reflection, **and that the glide vectors have the same length.**"

The answers given use the fact that 3 reflections lead to a glide. Assuming I can't use this result, what to do?

Here's some notation and rules given:
$t_a$:  *translation by a vector a*
$p_\theta:$ *rotation around the origin by angle $\theta$*
*r: reflection about the $e_1- axis$*

$p_{\theta}t_v = t_{p_{\theta}(v)}p_{\theta}$
$rt_v = t_{r(v)}r$
$rp_{\theta}= p_{-\theta}r$

All isometries are of the form $t_{v}p_{\theta}$ (orientation preserving) or $t_{v}p_{\theta}r$ (orientation reversing). I tried conjugating a glide, $g = t_{a}p_{\theta}r$, with a pure translation $t_{b}$ and I got:
$$t_{b}({t_{a}p_{\theta}r})t_{-b} = t_{b+a}p_{\theta}rt_{-b}=t_{b+a}t_{p_{\theta}(r(-b))}p_{\theta}r = t_{b+a+p_{\theta}(r(-b))}p_{\theta}r$$
The last expression is a glide (it's of the right form), but I don't see how the "glide vectors" have the same length. Any ideas?

Comment: "But they use results which were not mentioned in the book". I think that the answer at the duplicate is very clear and does not assume more theory than what is necessary. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @ Dietrich burde like I said in the question, they use the fact that a glide is 3 reflections, or that reflections generate the entire group, neither of which is discussed in the book.